# Python (Syntax that can hold value)

Tags: python

I have been trying to solve this problem by using the following function. What should I do to store all the digits input value and print them only at the end of the program when the program finishes to loop.

```
def compare(a):
    a=0
    while True:
        b=input("Enter an integer : ")
        if b.isdigit():
            k=n+1
            a=a+int(b)
        elif b.isalpha():
            if b.upper()=="Q":
                print("Digits\n",a,"\nTotal\n",a)
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Value. Enter again")
        elif b.isalnum():
            print("Value not recognized. Enter a valid value.")
        else:
            print("Unrecognized value is submitted. Enter again")
```

Comment: You need a `list`

Comment: Append each input to a list, then output that list at the end, e.g. with `print`

Comment: It just shows the last digit that I have entered.... It doesn't show the actual digits I've entered?

Comment: Can't I store all the digits that i have entered in a single variable?

Answer (score 0):

Updating you code as per question

```
def compare(a):
    a=0
    all_digits = []  # Empty list
    while True:
        b=input("Enter an integer : ")
        if b.isdigit():
            all_inputs.append(b)  # Append digit to list
            k=n+1
            a=a+int(b)
        elif b.isalpha():
            if b.upper()=="Q":
                print("Digits\n",a,"\nTotal\n",a)
                print("all digits: {}".format(all_digits))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Value. Enter again")
        elif b.isalnum():
            print("Value not recognized. Enter a valid value.")
        else:
            print("Unrecognized value is submitted. Enter again")
```

But this would be better code:

```
def compare(): # no need to pass any argument
    a = 0
    all_digits = []               # Empty list
    while True:
        b = raw_input("Enter an integer: ")
        if b.isdigit():
            all_digits.append(b)  # Append digit to list
            a = a + int(b)            # do not see 'k' being used anywhere
        elif b.isalpha():
            if b.upper() == "Q":
                print("Digits: {}\nTotal: {}\nSum: {}".format(", ".join(all_digits), len(all_digits), a))
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Value. Enter again")
        else:                     # no need of b.isalnum(). this will take care of both
            print("Unrecognized value is submitted. Enter again")
```

**Output**

```
Enter an integer: 1
Enter an integer: 2
Enter an integer: 3
Enter an integer: 4
Enter an integer: 5
Enter an integer: Q
Digits: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
Total: 5
Sum: 15
```

Comment: ##It prints the sum of entered value?

Comment: can you state you requirement clearly, you need to print all digits entered? total number of digits ? sum of all digits?

Comment: I need to print all digits that I've entered.... I already have the code to print the sum...

Comment: It seems that you want to store a string of digits. If you do `a=''; a = a + b` then `a` will be a concatenated string of digits. But your code is doing `a=0; a = a + int(b)` and that is adding numeric values, not concatenating characters.

Comment: @Puru, check now

Comment: Still incorrect .... I've got the answer already.....    But thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I assumed you want the Total to print the number of digits, and not the sum of the digits. A working version with comments about the changes compared to your code:

```
def compare(): # input value is not used
    a=[] # changed a to a list instead of integer
    n=0 # hold the number of digits that were entered
    while True:
        b=input("Enter an integer : ")
        if b.isdigit():
            n+=1 # add 1 to the number of digits that were entered, variable k is not used
            a.append(int(b)) #append the entered digit to list a
        elif b.isalpha():
            if b.upper()=="Q":
                print("Digits\n",*a,"\nTotal\n",n) # use print(*a) to print the list of numbers
                break
            else:
                print("Invalid Value. Enter again")
        elif b.isalnum():
            print("Value not recognized. Enter a valid value.")
        else:
            print("Unrecognized value is submitted. Enter again")
```

Comment: Can I change the horizontal printed list into Vertical?

Comment: @Tijn, no need of n+=1 also, you can directly use len(a)

Comment: If you want to print horizontal, you can use the join method for strings to join the list of strings by the '\n' character:

    print('\n'.join(map(str,a)),"\nTotal\n",n) # print horizontal list of digits